# Как создать круглую, крутящуюся кнопку для android?

Tags: android

как создать круглую, крутящуюся кнопку для android?
- вот таком [Виде](http://yadi.sk/d/VPCU3AVLCPaXy)

что бы одна кнопка была разделена две... обе кликабельными...
и что бы круглая кнопка крутилось.... когда его крутят влево и вправо..

Answer (score 1):

Создайте вертикальный Layout:
`<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rc_up"
            android:textColor="#00FF00"
            android:text="OK" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rc_down"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:text="Отмена" />
    </LinearLayout>`

---

Далее создайте в папке res/drawable два файла: rc_up и rc_down

---

rc_up.xml:
`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DC00FFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#AAFFFF00" />
</shape>`

---

rc_down:
`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#DC00FFFF" />
    <solid android:color="#AAFFFF00" />
</shape>`

---

А для поворота кнопок определите LinearLayout, и примените к нему RotateAnimation.